# Como posso ver o SQL gerado pelo Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework-core

Estou usando a versão 3.1 do EF Core, e estou tentando ver o SQL gerado desse código:

```
 var query = Db.Set<Area>()
    .Include(i => i.Extratos)
    .Include(i => i.Coordenadas)
    .Where(x => x.Ativo && x.FazendaId == fazendaId)
    .Select(x=> new Area {
        Coordenadas = x.Coordenadas.Where(x => x.Ativo),
        Extratos = x.AreaExtratos.Where(x => x.Ativo),
        Id = x.Id
    });
```

Adicionei esse trecho de código para verificar qual SQL o EF Core gerou.

```
var sql = ((System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery)query).ToTraceString();
```

Mas está me gerando esse erro:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1 XXX'
>   to type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery'.

Tentei essa solução também:

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(query.ToString());
```

Mas ela só aparece o SQL no console quando acontece um problema.

Comment: Se estiver rodando em um banco real, pode usar o SQL Profiler para ver a query.

Comment: @GabrielColetta não quer tentar adicionar uma resposta?

Comment: Até poderia, mas não sei se agregaria algo a mais do que já existe em documentação. Caso queira mais detalhes é só procurar na documentação por SQL Profiler: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De fato no Core o comportamento não é o mesmo do EF normal e não há uma forma pronta, essa é uma das desvantagens dele em relação ao *full*, pelo menos até agora.

Achei [algumas soluções no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37527783/221800) que mostram como fazer. Não é um código simples, mas é para você criar como uma biblioteca para uso seu. Vou reproduzir aqui a solução que pareceu mais interessante:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query;

public static string ToSql<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> query) where TEntity : class {
    var enumerator = query.Provider.Execute<IEnumerable<TEntity>>(query.Expression).GetEnumerator();
    var relationalCommandCache = enumerator.Private("_relationalCommandCache");
    var selectExpression = relationalCommandCache.Private<SelectExpression>("_selectExpression");
    var factory = relationalCommandCache.Private<IQuerySqlGeneratorFactory>("_querySqlGeneratorFactory");
    var sqlGenerator = factory.Create();
    var command = sqlGenerator.GetCommand(selectExpression);
    return command.CommandText;
}

private static object Private(this object obj, string privateField) => obj?.GetType().GetField(privateField, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)?.GetValue(obj);
private static T Private<T>(this object obj, string privateField) => (T)obj?.GetType().GetField(privateField, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)?.GetValue(obj);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/EntityFramework/SqlOutput.cs).

Aí pode aplicar esse método à *query* que fará o que o `ToString()` fazia no EF 6. Eu acho até mais correto a forma do Core, só que esse método deveria estar presente no Entity Framework pronto para uso.

Se não precisar no código tem ferramentas para ver isso, se é só análise e não parte da aplicação pode ser até mais interessante.